# Save to PDF loop not working

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

Solved.

The macro loops through a table and autofills values into the destination sheet and automatically saves as a pdf on the desktop with a specified file name for each row. It does not save them into a single pdf; however, if you have adobe acrobat it has a simple merge tool to combine them together.

```
  Sub AutoFill_export2pdf()
'

Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim CurBU As String
Dim CurOPRID As String
Dim CurName As String
Dim CurJournalID As String
Dim CurJournalDate As String
Dim FILE_NAME As String

 Sheets("List").Select

rowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count

Set Destsh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet")

For sourceRow = 2 To rowCount

CurOPRID = Range("A" & CStr(sourceRow)) 'OPRID
CurName = Range("B" & CStr(sourceRow)) 'Name
CurBU = Range("C" & CStr(sourceRow)) 'BU
CurJournalID = Range("D" & CStr(sourceRow)) 'Journal ID
CurJournalDate = Range("E" & CStr(sourceRow)) 'Journal Date

FILE_NAME = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "OTGL_" & "JRNL_" & CurBU & "_" &     CurJournalID & "_" & Format(CurJournalDate, "mm-dd-yyyy") & "_" & ".PDF"
CurName = "*" & CurName & "*"
CurBU = "*" & CurBU & "*"
CurJournalID = "*" & CurJournalID & "*"
CurJournalDate = "*" & CurJournalDate & "*"

Destsh.Range("K27") = CurName
Destsh.Range("D7") = CurBU
Destsh.Range("G7") = CurJournalID
Destsh.Range("I7") = CurJournalDate

On Error GoTo 0

Call SaveAsPDF(Destsh, FILE_NAME)

Sheets("List").Select

Next

End Sub


Public Sub SaveAsPDF(ByVal destSheet As Worksheet, ByVal PDFName As String)


On Error Resume Next
Kill PDFName

destSheet.Activate

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:= _
        PDFName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False,   OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub


Sub Autofill()
'

Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim CurBU As String
Dim CurName As String
Dim CurOPRID As String
Dim CurJournalID As String
Dim CurJournalDate As String
Dim FILE_NAME As String

CurName = "*" & CurName & "*"
CurBU = "*" & CurBU & "*"
CurJournalID = "*" & CurJournalID & "*"
CurJournalDate = "*" & CurJournalDate & "*"

Sheets("List").Select

rowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count

Set Destsh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet")

For sourceRow = 2 To rowCount

CurOPRID = Range("A" & CStr(sourceRow)) 'OPRID
CurName = Range("B" & CStr(sourceRow)) 'Name
CurBU = Range("C" & CStr(sourceRow)) 'BU
CurJournalID = Range("D" & CStr(sourceRow)) 'Journal ID
CurJournalDate = Range("E" & CStr(sourceRow)) 'Journal Date

FILE_NAME = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "OTGL_" & "JRNL_" & CurBU & "_" &    CurJournalID & "_" & Format(CurJournalDate, "mm-dd-yyyy") & "_" & ".PDF"

Destsh.Range("K27") = CurName
Destsh.Range("D7") = CurBU
Destsh.Range("G7") = CurJournalID
Destsh.Range("I7") = CurJournalDate

On Error GoTo 0

Call SaveAsPDF(Destsh, FILE_NAME)



Sheets("List").Select



Next


End Sub


End Sub
```

Comment: `saves the entire workbook in pdf-which is great but I only need sheet 1` then you do `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook | wb.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF` XD

Comment: Can you elaborate as to the difference between that line and mine...they appear the same to me.

Comment: I wrote `then you do` meaning I am stating what you did... so there is no difference.

Comment: My point is when you said you have `tried about thirty ways to Sunday`, I am doubting the veracity of your claim. My guess is you googled this code and didn't bother studying it at all. Edit: lol in before someone calls me rude again XD Yet, it's always OP who forces me to be blunt -_- Edit2: I guess I could just keep my mouth shut XD

Comment: I have come across this error prior to the current script as well as different ones. I know what the code means and I have gone through the processes to eliminate the error. I am here for help...this is a forum-where individuals discuss ideas and resolve problems. If the subject has been touched before, there are many many different solutions making each problem unique-If you can find an answer for my problem within the forum please link it so I can move on. So yes, I have done my research and it has provided little benefit. No need to call people out when they are just looking for help.

Answer (score 1):

You want to export just the Destination sheet (Destsh).  So use

```
Destsh.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
               filename:="fp", _
               Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
               IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
               IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
               OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Instead of

```
wb.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
               filename:="fp", _
               Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
               IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
               IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
               OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Also this will just save the file to "fp" you want to use something like

`filename:= fp & "\mysheetname.pdf"`

Comment: awww yeaaaa got to put you to 2k^^

Comment: I am getting a run time error '-214701887 document not saved...suggestions??

Comment: Then edit your original question to show your updated code. So I can see.  My guess is your filepath isn't built properly.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post you are still not refering to the variable fp (rather you are passing the literal string fp to filepath.  This doesn't cause the error you reference in your comment though.